# Strange html or css or javascript or whatever web page widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been asked to design a web page "widget" I do not know the name of the widget nor how to develop.
Please what is the name of the widget and how can I design it
I do not know whether it is a css, js or server side enabled stuff

Please find attached an image of the widget[image]

This is the widget only

[image]

**Update:**
I do think it is a breadcrumb, i think more like a wizard like thing. Which would list out what has been purchased before checking out

Comment: Looks breadcrumbs with a wizard-like shape. Are you listing all the purchased items this way? Sounds like a very bad way to do it.

Comment: It's not breadcrumbs, First box is Section Heading and other boxes are the list of purchase items. It can be easily created using HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure of what your question is but if you're referring to this  [image]

then that is what's called "Breadcrumbs". Here's an example of it being used with a popular Front end library called [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/breadcrumb/)